# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Oracle 8 JDK, and Tomcat 8

Tags: java, 18.04, openjdk, oracle, tomcat8

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as a Test server for some Java code where I am moving from WebLogic over to Tomcat. 
The code does not yet work with anything newer than Java 8, some of the packages I used are missing in Java 9 and 10, therefore it became a requirement to use Java 8.

I am attempting to get Tomcat8 installed via 'Apt install' in Bionic Beaver to work with Oracle 8. However, it seems Tomcat just wouldn't start up if Oracle 8 or Open JDK 8 is set as the primary JDK/JRE.

It works perfectly fine if I were to switch the JRE/JDK to Open JDK 10.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
yaCoder

Comment: So, it seems this is a known bug in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat8/+bug/1765616?comments=all

Waiting on a fix from the Debian group, https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=895866

fingers crossed :)